# Writing unit tests for functions in a pipeline

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have data which is processed sequentially, changing from

State A -> State B -> State C

If I had functions

`def convertAtoB(obj):...`

`def convertBtoC(obj):...`

How would I write a unit test to test convertBtoC? Since unit tests must be independent from each other, I can't call convertAtoB within the unit test to create the object of state B.

Answer (score 1):

Either create a mock version of `B` or create a full static version of `B` and pass it to `convertBtoC`.

For example:

`fetchJSONWeatherOverHTTP(weatherRequest)` -> `convertJSONWeatherIntoDataclass(jsonWeather)`

`weatherRequest` -> `jsonWeather` -> `weather`

In this case we'd need to mockup the `jsonWeather` object with fake data or use an old result because we would not want to perform an http request in our unit test.

Comment: I have thought of that, but I have a model which is subject to change. I don't want to couple the unit test to the implementation of B, which mocking would force. Is there some other way to accomplish this?

Comment: I can't imagine a way around that.  I would just not use a unit test and use an integration test in that case that calls through the pipeline.  If possible try to break everything out of the pipeline that doesn't need to be there and inject it with dependency injection as params to the pipeline functions.